# Python - How to split a string using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, string, split, data-cleaning

I want to split the following strings to get each attribute seperately:

```
String_one: 'archived': True, 'id': '30znq1', '_has_fetched': True
String_two: \\'hidden\\': False, \\'user_reports\\': [], \\'num_reports\\': None
```

I know that all of the attributes end with either ", '" or ", \\'"
Initially I was just using two string.spilt()

```
1) line.split(', \'')
2) line.split(', \\\'')
```

These both did the job, but I am working with a large amount of data and both of these are very general and the pattern was matched somewhere in the data it wasn't supposed to.

So I tried a re.split instead:

```
reg_split_no_esc = re.compile(', \'(.*\': .*)')
reg_split_esc    = re.compile(', \\\'(.*\\\': .*)')

line = re.split(reg_split_esc, line)
line = re.split(reg_split_no_esc, line)
```

The regular expressions are meant to find the first ", \'" and the split on this if it is followed by characters a single quote and a colon, its meant to catch what follows the ", \'".

reg_split_no_esc split on the first split condition but not for anymore, the other pattern is just not working.

Any help would be really appreciated

EDIT:
My first regular expression works but it only splits the first element and leaves the rest un-split so it looks like this:

```
_uniq': None

suggested_sort': None, 'secure_media_embed': {} 'report_reasons': None, '_params': {}
```

Comment: the "raw" prefix would probably help here.

Comment: Would that stop me needing to escape characters within the pattern?

Comment: I added the raw flag and tidied up the \ but I'm still having the same problems

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.
Specifically, the strings in your post are not python legal strings. Where did they come from?  Is this json?

Comment: Its not json, its data from reddit I pulled using praw, I then stored it in a text file. I trying to clean up the data. reg_split_no_esc = re.compile(', \'(.*\': .*)') is working but its only finding the first example and splitting the list into one attribute followed by the rest of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness sake I figured out the answer, it was the [lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

The final pattern looks like:

```
re.compile(', \'(?=\w*\': )')
```

Cheers